# String.replaceAll(regex, repl) not working correctly on certain devices

Tags: java, android, json

So I'm currently working on an android app and for debugging purposes I'm logging all actions. The problem is that the API I'm working with takes a plain text password for authentication and as I can't get a functional account for the API, I have someone else testing the app for me and therefore need to obfuscate the password anytime it appears in my logs.

This is my current code to transform my JSON request to a string and obfuscate all occurences of the plain text password:

```
public static String jorToString(JsonObjectRequest jor){

    String body;
    try{
        body = new String(jor.getBody());
        body = body.replaceAll("password=.*","password=***********");
        body = body.replaceAll("\"password\":\".*\",","\"password\":\"***********\",");
    }catch (Exception e){
        body = "null";
    }

    String debug = "URL: " + jor.getUrl() + "\nMethod: " + (jor.getMethod() == 0 ? "GET" : jor.getMethod() == 1 ? "POST" : jor.getMethod()) + "\nBody: " + body + "\nHeaders: ";

    try{
        debug += jor.getHeaders();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        debug += e.toString();
    }

    return debug;
}
```

Here's an example of what the request body looks like before obfuscating:

```
Body: {"grant_type":"password","client_id":"abc","client_secret":"abc","email":"my.email@domain.com","password":"plain-text-pwd"}
```

and what I want it to look like:

```
Body: {"grant_type":"password","client_id":"abc","client_secret":"abc","email":"my.email@domain.com","password":"************"}
```

Now the problem is that when I test this on my phone (android 4.3) it works like a charm. On the other hand, on my superior's phone the password stays in plain text in the log file meaning he has to manually change it before sending me the log file.

Any help figuring out why the replaceAll function doesn't seem to work on newer versions of android would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried checking that your object `jor` is strictly the same on each devices ? The fact that `replaceAll` has different behaviors on some devices seems very unlikely to me

Comment: Yup, I'm blind... guess I must have been very tired Friday... Turns out the json body had password/email in a different order on the different devices. Thanks for having me check!

Comment: You're welcome !